# Error while retrieving BLOB data. Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, oracle, arrays, blob, memorystream

I have below code in C# which is for retrieving BLOB type data from ORACLE into a `byte[]`.

**CODE:**

```
private MemoryStream GetStatement(int loginId, OracleConnection con)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var oraQuery = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT statement_file from user_account_statement where login_id=" + loginId + "", con))
        {

            using (var oraQueryResult = oraQuery.ExecuteReader())
                if (oraQueryResult != null)
                {
                    oraQueryResult.Read();
                    var blob = new Byte[(oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                    oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                    //updated.
                    memoryStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                }
        }
        return memoryStream;
    }
```

**Error**

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

at Code line:

```
var blob = new Byte[(oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by parametrized query. Working code below:

```
private static MemoryStream GetStatement(OracleConnection con, int loginId)
{
 var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 using (
 var oraQuery = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT statement_file from user_account_statement where login_id=:1, con))
 {
  oraQuery.BindByName = true;
  oraQuery.Parameters.Add(":1", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = loginId;
  using (var oraQueryResult = oraQuery.ExecuteReader())
  if (oraQueryResult != null)
  {
   while (oraQueryResult.Read())
   {
    var blob = new Byte[(oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
    oraQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
    memoryStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
   }
  }
 }
 return memoryStream;
}
```